# How to ignore accents in Azure Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Does Azure Search support some way of ignoring accented characters? For example, if somebody searches for **e** it should include **é** characters in the search. Or would we need to add some converting at the moment of building the Azure Search Index?

Any recomendations welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Please use the ASCII folding analyzer on your field. To do that, set the analyzer property on your field to

analyzer:"standardasciifolding.lucene"

Alternatively, use a [language specific analyzer](http://aka.ms/linguistics) e.g. analyzer:"fr.microsoft".
To learn more about analyzers in Azure Search take a look [here](http://aka.ms/azsanalysis).

Note: Different language analyzers treat diacritic marks differently, use the [Analyze API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer) to test analyzer behavior.

Comment: Any idea how the same can be implemented in the azure filter (not the search query)?