# Azure Search - unaccent

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Trying to figure out how to get ignore accents ability in azure search. Texts in my application are in Polish lanuage. For searchable fields I tried to use pl.microsoft and    pl.lucene analyzer. Both of them are able to change singular form to plural. What I'm not able to achive is ignoring accents. The only way that I found ([How to ignore accents in Azure Search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544784/how-to-ignore-accents-in-azure-search)) is to use standardasciifolding.lucene analyzer. It ignores accents but on the other hand doesn't change form from singular to plural. Is there any way to combine two analyzers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution, but I'm not sure if it's the simplest approach or maybe I complicated it too much:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": false,
            "filterable": false,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": false,
            "facetable": false,
            "key": true,
            "indexAnalyzer": null,
            "searchAnalyzer": null,
            "analyzer": null
        },
        {
            "name": "name",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": false,
            "filterable": true,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": false,
            "facetable": false,
            "key": false,
            "indexAnalyzer": null,
            "searchAnalyzer": "pl_analyzer",
            "analyzer": null
        }
    ],
    "scoringProfiles": [],
    "defaultScoringProfile": "",
    "corsOptions": null,
    "suggesters": [],
    "analyzers":[
    {
      "name":"pl_analyzer",
      "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "tokenizer":"polish_tokenizer",
      "tokenFilters":[ "lowercase", "asciifolding"  ]
    }],
    "tokenizers": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.MicrosoftLanguageStemmingTokenizer",
      "name": "polish_tokenizer",
      "isSearchTokenizer": true,
      "language": "polish"
    }
    ],
    "tokenFilters": [],
    "charFilters": []
}
```

Comment: This is the right way to solve your problem. The asciifolding filter maps "accented" characters in languages where the accented character is it's own character (such as Polish) into the base latin script. That achieves removal of the accent.

Also, the MicrosoftLanguageStemmingTokenizer, does stemming (one such effect is removing plural forms, it also might remove tense related suffixes).

You can refer to documentation here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search#TokenFilters about the different token filters available in Azure search.