# Returning accented as well as normal result set via azure search filters

Tags: azure, search, lucene, odata, azure-search-.net-sdk

Does anyone know how to ensure we can return normal result as well as accented result set via the azure search filter. For e.g the below filter query in Azure search returns a name called unicorn when i check for record with name unicorn.

```
 var result= searchServiceClient.Documents.SearchAsync<myDto>("*",new SearchParameters
            {
                SearchFields = new List<string> {"Name"},
                Filter = "Name eq 'unicorn'"
            });
```

This is all good but what i want is i want to write a filter such that it returns record named **unicorn** as well as record named **únicorn** (please note the first accented character) provided that both record exist.

This can be achieved when searching for such name via the search query using language or Standard ASCII folding search analyzer as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544784/how-to-ignore-accents-in-azure-search). What i am struggling to find out is how can we implement the same with azure filters?

Please let me know if anyone has got any solutions around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters are applied on the non-analyzed representation of the data, so I don’t think there’s any way to do any type of linguistic analysis on filters. One way to work around this is to manually create a field which only do lowercasing + asciifloding (no tokenization) and then search lucene queries that look like this:

```
    "normal search query terms" AND customFilterColumn:"filtérValuèWithÄccents"
```

Basically the document would both need to match the search terms in any field AND also match the filter term in the “customFilterColumn”.  This may not be sufficient for your needs, but at least you understand the art of the possible.

Comment: Are you saying Filters cannot be applied on analyzed fields or filters do not work on non analyzed fields. Also for the new field are you recommending custom analyzer ?

Comment: Got it Luis. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Using filters it won't work unless you specify in advance all the possibilities:

for example:

`$filter=name eq 'unicorn' or name eq 'únicorn'`

You'd better work with a different analyzer that will change accents to it's root form. As another possibility, you can try fuzzy search:

```
search=unicorn~&highlight=Name
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My understanding is that analyzers dont have any effect when it comes to filters. They only work on the search query.

Comment: your problem is not the filter itself, but deal with accents or not. If you rely on an analyzer to remove accents and only work with root form, then problem solved

Comment: with the above setting i used two different analyzers turn by turn. en.microsoft to begin with and then standardasciifolding.lucene. With both analyzers i only get the normal record but not accented records in the result when it comes to using filters. If you are aware of any analyzer that could handy please let me know

Comment: you must use one with ascii folding. try standardasciifolding.lucene https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers#TokenFilters

Comment: Thats what i used. It works when i do not use the filter and just search for the name unicorn directly in the search query. in this case it brings both unicorn and únicorn. However if i include the filter as mentioned above it only brings out unicorn (regular text). I am almost convinced filters does not cater for accented characters no matter which anlayzer we use.

Comment: you're right ... filter is pretty much a "where clause" which means that you must provide both ways as I said or it will only return the exact match

Comment: Thank you Thiago for your inputs on this issue.